# getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput' in VSC even though its installed

Tags: python, pynput

My VSC stopped seeing pynput as installed on the device. I was working on something, accidentally quit VSC, upon reopening it, Pynput was no longer being recognized. VSC itself updated but that never caused any issues.

i've already tried using all the commands to install pynput and all came up with the same thing. "Requirement already satisfied: pynput in.. (path here)"

I uninstalled and installed pynput several times over aswell and nothing changed.
Also tried restarting my pc. still didnt fix anything

here's my code incase something is wrong in it:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = pynput.Controller()


x = 1

def looper():
    while (x == 1):
        keyboard.press('a')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        looper()
looper()
```

Comment: Where is it installed and where is VS Code looking for Python modules?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it via changing Python Interpreters [image]

had to switch to the Microsoft Store one for some reason? But this fixed it and Pynput is once again recognized by VSC.

Comment: For [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121), please do not post code as an image. It is better to add code in a codeblock. Thanks